# port this template to lualatex

Tags: luatex, koma-script, classicthesis

I am new to lualatex and I am trying to port the template at this link http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/TesiClassica.zip from pdflatex to lualatex. This template uses komascript, classicthesis and arsclassica, (package written by the template's author)

I got all a bunch of "undefined font shape" warning, and obviously the result is quite different.

What should I do to ensure that the output will be the same?

I have done some research: I guess I need to set up with `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont`, and maybe defines some `\newfontfamily` for all different cases in which different font are used (section title, chapter, caption, etc..)

Ps. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 with no new fonts installed.

PPS I do recognize that I am not providing directly a MWE, because I think it would be redundant to copy-paste the entire template, as the goal of this question is to exactly reproduce the pdftex out with lualatex.

EDIT.

I got this bunch of warnings that I think are the problem.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/pplj/m/n' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/pplj/m/sc' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/pplj/m/sl' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/pplj/m/it' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/fvm/m/n' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/pplj/bx/n' undefined
```

Comment: Unless you run into a LuaTeX bug or a change due to the differences in some parts of _e.g._ the hyphenation system, running an example from pdfTeX with LuaTeX will give you exactly the same result. What exactly are you aiming for there?

Comment: well, I got a lot of warnings about missing fonts, and I think that is the problem. For example, the template uses the euler math font, and that need to be set-up in lua latex using `\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathit->\mathup}]{Neo Euler}` after adding the necessary otf file to my font. Anyway, I am editing the question to add the warnings I think that are problem.

Comment: Without editing anything you should be able to compile exactly the same source with Lualatex (there might be some utf-8 problem in the titlepage though). Now I could ask you @thunder1123 a question: why do you need the features of lualatex for in the end having a result similar to the one of pdflatex?

Comment: Well, I like the font-related flexibility of lualatex,and anyway, is that wrong experimenting and learning new features?

Comment: There is no problem with that, but the main problem with lualatex is the math font handling. If I'm not mistaken this template uses Palatino, so choosing tex-gyre pagella math for this would be preferable, as indicated by @egreg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can make it work with some small adjustments, but only with XeLaTeX:

1. Remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
2. Remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (but make sure your files are UTF-8 encoded)
3. Remove the `eulermath` option to `classicthesis`
4. Add the following before `\usepackage{bookmark}`:

   ```
   \usepackage{unicode-math}
   \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
   \setsansfont{Iwona}
   \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
   \setmathfont[range={\mathit->\mathup}]{Neo Euler}
   ```

Run through XeLaTeX.

If you insist with LuaLaTeX, you need to change how `\textls` is defined; so, add just before `\begin{document}`,

```
\renewrobustcmd{\textls}[2][100]{%
  {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=\number\numexpr#1/10\relax}#2}%
}
```

Comment: I am still getting a warning: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/fvm/m/n' undefined`. By the way, what your lualatex trick does?

Comment: @thunder1123 You're loading Beramono, which can't be used with `fontspec`. There are other monospaced fonts to be loaded with `\setmonofont`. LuaLaTeX seems to choke on the default `\textls`, I don't know why: a bad interaction with `microtype`, I guess.

Comment: Just to know, with evince, the two main fonts look different, with lualatex it seems "bolder", but when I zoom in, the fonts seems identical. Does it depends only on the pdf engine?

Comment: @thunder1123 TeX Gyre Pagella is not exactly the same as the font called by `\usepackage{mathpazo}`; possibly it's related to hinting in connection with antialiasing: just a viewer problem.